# Weird behavior under chrome and $.ajax after chrome update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I've an asp.net mvc5 application that on a loginpage does the following Ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var formObj = $(".login-form");

    $("form input[name=username]").val("user");
    $("form input[name=password]").val("password1!");

    formObj.submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("test");

        validator = formObj.validate();

        if (validator.checkForm()) {

            var form = formObj.get();

            var rememberMe = $("input:checkbox[name=remember]:checked").val() ? true : false;
            $(form.rememberMe).val(rememberMe);

            args = {
                form: form,
                userName: $(form.username).val(),
                password: $(form.password).val(),
                remember: rememberMe
            }

            var url = @Url.Content("~/api/auth");
            func = $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: args,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("success")
                    if (data["ResponseStatus"]["ErrorCode"] == null) {

                        @if(Request.Params.Get("redirect") != null)  {
                        <text>
                        window.location = "@Request.Params.Get("redirect")";
                        </text>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <text>
                        window.location = "@Url.Content("~/Home")";
                        </text>
                    }
                    }
                }
            });
            }
    });

});
```

If I put this piece of code

```
var url = @Url.Content("~/api/auth");
```

it works, otherwise if I quote the url string (as it should be correct)

```
var url = "@Url.Content("~/api/auth")";
```

it hangs the browser.

This only happens under chrome as first iussue was reported with Chrome Version 43.0.2357.65 m

What is wrong?

Thanks

## UPDATE #1

I've noticed that the problem is there

```
               $.ajax({
                url: "/someurl",
                data: args,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("success")
                    if (data["ResponseStatus"]["ErrorCode"] == null) {

                        
                        window.location = "/someotherurl/";
                        
                    }
                }
            });
```

If I sue ajax it breaks...if I use $.post or $.get it works...

Comment: I'm no .NET expert but if you post the resulting javascript instead of this server side code I think the problem might be easier to spot. Maybe `@Url.Content()` quotes the resulting string automatically or so.

Comment: The problem was with $.ajax itself and not the quotes...